# How to open a user control as popup using jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery

can anyone explain....I am beginner

Comment: Please explain in more detail, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: What about [this example](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) do you not understand?

Comment: And also post some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good link to get lots of information..http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog

Very basicly for it to work you need to have a div that will be your dialog..

```
    <div ID="myDialog" Title="The title for my dialog">
         This will be the content of my dialog
    </div>
<a href="#" ID="btn">Click for Dialog</a>
```

Then you need to call it with some jquery..

```
$(document).ready(function() 
     $('#btn').live("click", function(){
         $("#myDialog").dialog();
     });
});
```

When the link is clicked the dialog will show.

Comment: suppose in the div tag i have 2 textboxes 3 buttons. so i have to make div visibility hidden. so when i click that button div will open right......

Comment: right.. hide it until its needed for use in the dialog :)